# VBA - code that returns me to the original state (perhaps turning a field type from "text" to "number")

Tags: excel, vba, text, numbers

I have a vba command that adds 0 (where I need it) to a specific rule that is relevant to my purpose.
The command turns the cells into a "text" type.
I am interested in a correction command that cancels my order (in some cases I have to go back) Here is my code:

```
Sub Add_Zeros()

    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

    For Each CL In Selection.Cells
        Select Case Len(CL)
            Case 8: CL.Value = "0" & CL.Value
            Case 9: CL.Value = IIf(Left(CL.Value, 1) = 5, "0", "") & CL.Value
            Case "" 'do nothing
            Case Else
       End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Do you have a code that restores the previous action? Perhaps returning the cells to their original type to "number"

Thanks in advance ,

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zeroes unless you format the cell as `000000000`. You can return the numerical ,value with `val(CL.Value)` or `int(CL.Value)` or `CLng(CL.Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is remove leading zeros, you can do something like this:

```
Sub remove_Zeros()

    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works very well , thank you very very much ,
Blessed be from heaven .